# Ignoring duplicated values within 5 rows

Tags: excel

This is quite difficult to explain so I have attached an excel file here: http://minus.com/mQF3Qrsoh

If you look at the excel file column F is what I have currently, column G is what I want.

Basically, the formula will look in the past 5 values for a value of "x" if it finds it, then the next 5 rows are *

I accomplish this by the formula: `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP("x",E11:E15, 1, FALSE)), "", "*")`

However, if there is a second x within 5 cells of another x, then the second x should be ignored completely.

That's the part I don't know what to do.

See this screenshot as well, if you dont want to download excel file:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution that uses 1 column and feeds my needs. I had to end up using a separate indicator to signal the start of a group, in this case "x" and then for each following 4, "xx".

This is for F10:

`=IF(AND(COUNTIF(F6:F9,"x")=0,E10="x"),"x",IF(COUNTIF(F6:F9,"x")=0,"","xx"))`

Where column E lies the raw data.

Answer (score 1):

Create another column with a formula that only returns valid `x` 's (lets assume col `H`)
Example formula for cell `H15`

```
=IF(E15="x",IF(ISNA(MATCH("x",E10:E14,0)),"x",""),"")
```

then your formula in column `G` becomes

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH("x",H11:H15,0)), "", "*")
```

Comment: Nothing comes to mind yet.  It might be possible, but will probably be big and ugly!  Any particular reason you don't want another column?  Would a vba solution be ok?

Comment: Well because it's going to be in an organized column and I don't want an extra row if it's not needed, also the solution doesnt work if say  there is an x between two x's of which if ignoring the middle x, the 2 x's have a space longer than 5...pic here:http://minus.com/mi1gf94ww   ..the x between the 6 and 7 should have been triggered because its 6 away from the first x  (the 2nd x is ignored)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
=IF(AND(E10="x";F9<=1);5;MAX(F9-1;0))
```

[image: example]

this solution forces to change the way you detect teh event from cell="*" to cell>0

Comment: This is a very elegant solution but again suffers from requiring two columns

Comment: not necesarily, the formuale yields 0 when there no "x" and yields <> 0 (values from 1 to 5) when there is a "x" in the five previous row, dsiregarding repetitions.

Comment: Yes but it depends on the values of the same column to determine if its <>0 or 0. I wasn't able to get it to work with 1 formula. the `*` key does not have to be used, in reality this will be `15` instead of `*`